# Class structure for a x,y grid of inputs

Tags: c#

I'm struggling how to implement a class for an x,y grid of type bool. Is this the most efficient way?

[image]

```
public class Grid {
   public Readers Timeband0 { get; set; }
   public Readers Timeband1 { get; set; }
   ...
   public Readers Timeband9 {get; set; }
}

public class Readers {
   public bool reader 1 { get; set; }
   public bool reader 2 { get; set; }
   ....
   public bool reader 10 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you heard of arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have prepared a method for designing a network. You can change the elements inside the structure to your needs

```
public class Row
{
   public List<Cell> Cells;
   public Row()
   {
      Cells = new List<Cell>();
   }
}
public class Cell
{
   public int X { get; set; }
   public int Y { get; set; }
   public bool Value { get; set; }
   public Cell(int _X, int _Y, bool _Value)
   {
      X = _X;
      Y = _Y;
      Value = _Value;
   }
}
```

now use

```
void FillList()
{
    List<Row> rows = new List<Row>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
    {
       Row row = new Row();
       for (int j = 1; j <= 8; j++)
       {
          bool value = true;
          if (j % 2 == 0)
               value = true;

          row.Cells.Add(new Cell(i, j, value));
       }
       rows.Add(row);
    }


    //show output
    string Output = "";
    int d = 0;
    foreach (var row in rows)
    {
       if (d == 0)
       {
          Output = Output + "         ";
          for (int k = 1; k <= 8; k++)
          {
             Output = Output + k + "         ";
          }
          Output += Environment.NewLine;
          Output += Environment.NewLine;
       }

       Output = Output + d + "    ";
       foreach (var cell in row.Cells)
       {
          Output += cell.Value + "    ";
       }

       Output += Environment.NewLine;
       Output += Environment.NewLine;
       d++;
    }
}
```

output

[image]